# How to access JS object properties in Wasm (Rust)?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm using wasm bindgen and I have following function :

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn obj(o: &JsValue){
console::log_1(o);
}
```

and in js I call this function `obj({name: "john"});`
and it works fine, but when i try to `console::log_1(o.name);`
it gives error `unknown field` pointing at `name`

Comment: The error with `unknown field` occurs when compiling or at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JsValue` does not have a field `name`. To get this field you have to declare the JS object.

**Variant 1**

Add serde to your dependencies:

```
serde = "^1.0.101"
serde_derive = "^1.0.101"
```

Rust code:

```rust
extern crate serde;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub name: String,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn obj(o: &JsValue){
    let user: User = o.into_serde().unwrap();
    console::log_1(user.name);
}
```

**Variant 2**

Another way is to use wasm-bindgen directly but I never used it. It should work like this I think:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct User {
    pub name: String,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn obj(o: User){
    console::log_1(o.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a third variant: Use **`js_sys::Reflect::get`**.

In your case it would look like this:

```rust
let value = js_sys::Reflect::get(o, &"name".into())?;
console::log_1(value);
```

Please check the [wasm_bindgen docs for **Accessing Properties of Untyped JavaScript Values**](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/accessing-properties-of-untyped-js-values.html).