How can I determine what type Or how to retrieve data from js_sys::JsValue passed back from an async "read" callback
Big edit now complete minimal test app a tree of files to be in the structure below.
The issue I have is I have tried lots of things and been looking at docs on how to get access to the data in the "Promise" spawned by the reader in web_test.rs. everything up to there works.
assemble the project tree from the files in the code blocks in the structure below. in a shell CD to the root, and run ./build.sh
this builds it all and spawns a local web server from that you can run a browser looking at it.  This at least on my macbook runs on Firefox, Chrome, and Brave browsers.
(root) | Cargo.toml
       | test_file.txt
       | web_src | index.html
       | build.sh
       | src | main.rs
             | test_web.rs

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "minimal_web_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# this is needed for the RustRover "wasmpack" build
[lib]
name = "minimal_web_test_lib"
path = "src/main.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[features]

[dependencies]

bevy = {  version = "0.14"}
bevy_math = "0"

uuid = "1"

# optional = true packages only included if wasm32 feature is set.
web-sys = { version = "0.3.69", features = [
    "Window", "HtmlElement", "Request", "Headers", "RequestInit", "RequestMode","Event", "EventTarget",
    "MouseEvent", "DragEvent", "DataTransfer", "DataTransferItemList", "DataTransferItem", "FileList",
    "File", "FileReader", "DomException", "Blob", "FileSystemHandle", "FileSystemHandleKind",
    "FileSystemDirectoryHandle", "Url", "ReadableStream", "ReadableStreamGetReaderOptions", "ReadableStreamReaderMode",
    "ReadableStreamByobReader", "BinaryType", ] }

wasm-bindgen = {  version = "0.2.92" }
wasm-bindgen-futures = {  version = "0.4.42"}

# Enable a small amount of optimization in debug mode
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 1

# Enable high optimizations for dependencies (incl. Bevy), but not for our code:
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3

test_file.txt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://127.0.0.1:8000/</string>
</dict>
</plist>

web_src/index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Peters Wasm Test</title>
    <style>
        .bevy_canvas { padding-right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; }
        /* the canvas *must not* have any border or padding, or mouse coords will be wrong */
        canvas.bevy_canvas {
            border: 0px none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">

    <div style="padding-top: 20px; text-align:center; margin:auto;">
            <canvas class="bevy_canvas" id="minimal-test-canvas">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
        import init from './minimal_web_test.js'
        init().catch((error) => {
            if (!error.message.startsWith("Using exceptions for control flow, don't mind me. This isn't actually an error!")) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

build.sh
#!/bin/bash

# build
mkdir -p ./pkg;
cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown;
wasm-bindgen --no-typescript --target web --out-dir ./pkg/ --out-name minimal_web_test \
               ./target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/minimal_web_test.wasm;
cp ./web-src/index.html ./pkg/index.html;
cd ./pkg
echo "server serving: http://127.0.0.1:8000"
python3 -m http.server;   # run local web server of your choice you will have to kill it with ctrl-c !


src/main.rs
#![allow(warnings)]

use bevy::math::*;
use bevy::prelude::*;
mod test_web;


pub fn main() {
    let mut binding = App::new();
    let mut app = &mut binding;

    app.add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
        primary_window: Some(Window {
            canvas: Some("#minimal-test-canvas".into()),
            title: "theSame.page Wasm".to_string(),
            ..default()
        }),
        ..default()
    }));

    app.add_systems(Startup, (
        test_web::test_drop_on_page,
    ));
    app.run();
}

src/test_web.rs
use std::fmt::Formatter;
use std::io::BufReader;

use bevy::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;
use wasm_bindgen_futures::js_sys::{
    Function,
    Promise,
    Uint8Array,
    Int8Array,
    ArrayBuffer,
    Object,
    Reflect,
};

use wasm_bindgen_futures::{ JsFuture };

use web_sys::{
    HtmlCanvasElement,
    HtmlElement,
    Request,
    RequestInit,
    RequestMode,
    Event,
    EventTarget,
    MouseEvent,
    DragEvent,
    DataTransfer,
    DataTransferItemList,
    DataTransferItem,
    FileList,
    File,
    Blob,
    FileSystemHandle,
    FileSystemHandleKind,
    FileSystemDirectoryHandle,
    FileReader,
    DomException,
    Url,
    ReadableStream,
    ReadableStreamGetReaderOptions,
    ReadableStreamByobReader,
    ReadableStreamReaderMode,
    ReadableStreamReaderMode::Byob,
};

fn url_promise_success(uri: String) {
    info!("url promise success {:?}", uri);
}
fn url_promise_failure(uri: String) {
    info!("url promise failure {:?}", uri);
}
fn print_jstype( jv: &JsValue) {
    info!("is string {:?}", jv.is_string());
    info!("is object {:?}", jv.is_object());
    info!("is array {:?}", jv.is_array());
    if jv.is_bigint() {
        info!("is i64");
    } else if let Some(eff64) = jv.as_f64() {
        info!("is f64");
    }
    info!("is undefined {:?}", jv.is_undefined());
    info!("is null {:?}", jv.is_null());

}

pub fn test_drop_on_page() {

    info!("wasm drop test START");

    let window = web_sys::window().unwrap();
    let document = window.document().unwrap();
    let canvas = document.get_element_by_id("minimal-test-canvas").unwrap();

    let mut clicks = 0;
    let on_drop = Closure::<dyn FnMut(_)>::new(move |e: DragEvent | {

        info!("#### we got a Drop !!");
        e.stop_propagation();
        e.prevent_default();

        // get position of drop in html canvas element.
        let rect = e
            .target()
            .expect("event doesn't have a target")
            .dyn_into::<HtmlElement>()
            .expect("event target should be of type HtmlElement")
            .get_bounding_client_rect();

        let drop_x = (e.client_x() as f64) - rect.left();
        let drop_y = (e.client_y() as f64) - rect.top();

        info!("drop_x : {} ; drop_y : {}", drop_x, drop_y);


        if let Some(data) = e.data_transfer() {
            info!("    #### we got Data !!");
            // TODO: loop through list of transfer items of different types

            let types = data.types();
            let type0 = types.get(0).as_string().unwrap(); // TODO: always ok ?
            let item0: DataTransferItem = data.items().get(0).unwrap();

            match type0.as_str() {
                "Files" => {  // handles TWO cases in same block
                    let is_files = type0.as_str() == "Files";

                    let files = data.files().unwrap();
                    let len = files.length();  // length of array

                    let file = files.get(0).unwrap();

                    let blob: &Blob = file.as_ref();  // uri
                    let fsize = blob.size();

                    // this seems to put a link in the browser cache for this item to be used
                    // by the URI based calls.
                    // let ooo = Url::create_object_url_with_blob(blob);

                    let stream: ReadableStream = blob.stream();
                    let mut opt = ReadableStreamGetReaderOptions::new();
                    opt.mode(ReadableStreamReaderMode::Byob);

                    let reader_obj = stream.get_reader_with_options(&opt);  // JsValue(ReadableStreamByobReader)

                    info!("obj is: {:?}", reader_obj);

                    let jval: &JsValue = reader_obj.as_ref();

                    info!("jval is: {:?}", jval);

                    let dref = jval.dyn_ref::<ReadableStreamByobReader>();

                    let byob_reader = dref.unwrap();

                    info!("reader is: {:?}", byob_reader);

                    {
                        // create buffer to read into
                        let array = Uint8Array::new_with_length((fsize as i32) as u32);
                        info!("##### length is {:?}", fsize);
                        info!("###### Array length after create is: {:?}", array.byte_length());

                        // as_ref() for the Uint8Array returns an "Object" representing it.
                        let promise = byob_reader.read_with_array_buffer_view(&array);


                        let read_ok = Closure::<dyn FnMut(_)>::new(move |e: JsValue| {
                            let jv: &JsValue = &e; // .as_ref();
                            print_jstype(&e);

                            let o_opt = Object::try_from(&e); // -> Option<&Object>

                            info!("###### o_opt is {:?}", o_opt.unwrap() );
                            print_jstype(e.dyn_ref().unwrap());
                        });
                        promise.then(&read_ok);
                        read_ok.forget();  // TODO: leaks ! hold ref somewhere
                    }
                }
                _ => {
                    info!("unhandled drop type {:?}", type0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    let on_dragenter = Closure::<dyn FnMut(_)>::new(move |e: DragEvent | {
        e.stop_propagation();
        e.prevent_default();
    });
    let on_dragover = Closure::<dyn FnMut(_)>::new(move |e: DragEvent| {
        e.stop_propagation();
        e.prevent_default();
    });

    if let Some(dyn_canvas) = wasm_bindgen::JsCast::dyn_ref::<web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement>(&canvas) {
        dyn_canvas.set_ondragenter(Some(on_dragenter.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
        dyn_canvas.set_ondragover(Some(on_dragover.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
        dyn_canvas.set_ondrop(Some(on_drop.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    } else {
        info!("######  NO canvas !!");
    }

    // TODO: leaks ! keep references somewhere
    on_drop.forget();
    on_dragover.forget();
    on_dragenter.forget();
}


After it builds, launch the browser at the link printed to the console, and drag the icon for the ./test_file.txt and drop it on the black rectangle in the test web page.  It will print the item in the parameter to the promise.then(a closure). but I have tried many ways to get a Rust struct out of it and haven't succeeded.
When this works, I will put a cleaned up version on github as an example.

What's a js_sys::JsValue? js_sys doesn't define that type or trait.

Also what are e fsize byob_reader …

@cafce25
fsize comes from the blob.size() retrieved from the "DataTransfer" in the drop event ( on the element in the html page).  It is the size I create the array for to read the file into.  it is the same size reported by ls -l in a shell for the file.
The data logged to the console via {:?} in the callaback for the JsValue is the same length as well.  So it seems to me the read is succesful and the data is proper.
My problem is accessing the buffer fro the API in the callback to use the data :)

Please respond by [edit]ing your question to include the missing information, not in comments. Also remember questions here are supposed to be self contained!

Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437723/how-to-access-js-object-properties-in-wasm-rust

@cafce25. so that sort of says I need to access a field in the Object
first get the JsValue from the object, then get the field "value:" from it>
the text print shows an ascii "jason jscript" like string of an array.  The Byob the docs seem to say it will copy bytes directly without any serde operation.  Anyway for now I just want it to work and can optimise later :)

They say "The promise fulfills with an object that has properties value and done when data comes available", the dupe explains several ways to get data from such an untyped Object, some require serde some don't. They also explain what the done field means.

@cafce25. simple in javascript world :) It is the chain or as_ref() and dyn_ref etc and the types to expect at each step in web_sys world I am trying to get.  To get from the JsValue passed into the callback to the value it read in, and passed into the callback.

The type returned is Object, there isn't a deeper type, JS doesn't have types beyond that and a couple of primitives.

@cafce25. as I have discovered and found in the accessors from a JsValue.  But the  JsValue represents a type containing a u8 array probably having to be retrieved with a dyn_ref() or dyn_into() to get it. ( the value: in the JsValue )  dyn_ref() does require a type to assign into though.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. a piece of code we can run ourselves and observe the problem.

@ChayimFriedman. Ok will try to extricate it from the app - let me know where to send a zip file or the format you want.

Do not send anything. Post the MRE here. If it's too long, that means it is not a Minimal example. Minimize it. Instructions are on the page I linked.

@ChayimFriedman. it would consist of a Cargo file, a few line script to build it, a src/main.rs file a tiny text file to drop on the app, and a small html file. It would require rust toolchain and cargo build utilities be installed as prerequisites.  Without the context, one could not build and run it.

@peterk That's fine, as long as it the most minimal you can get. Still post it in the question.

@ChayimFriedman done :). Quesition updated.

Are you really unable to reproduce the problem without bevy, your CSS, and this big blob of JavaScript? Please create the most minimal reproducible example.
